# Rails facebook app and Third party UID's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebooker, facebooker2

I have a rails facebook app that uses Facebooker2 and the blog post says they are moving to third party uid's instead of normal uid's. What would it take to make the migrations to keep my app working?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to [this Facebook blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/431).

Take note that the third party UID change is more of a legal issue than a technical one. This advice shouldn't be considered legal advice.

Third party UIDs are not replacing Facebook's UIDs. However, you are now prohibited from sharing Facebook UIDs with other companies. If you are exporting your data to someone other than yourself then you would have to run some changes in the export mechanism.

However, if you're only using Facebook UIDs internally, you don't have to change anything.